# Starting Microsoft Edge from MFC with web file paramater

Tags: visual-c++, microsoft-edge, spawn

If I open up a console prompt I can type this command:

`start msedge "d:\HTML\Verticle Alignment.HTM"`

It starts Microsoft Edge and opens the web page.

So I tried to do this programmatically in a test program using MFC:

```
void CMFCApplication8Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    ExecuteProgram(_T("start"), _T("msedge d:\\HTML\\Verticle Alignment.HTM"));
}


BOOL CMFCApplication8Dlg::ExecuteProgram(CString strProgram, CString strArguments)
{
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO    se = { 0 };
    MSG                 sMessage;
    DWORD               dwResult;

    se.cbSize = sizeof(se);
    se.lpFile = strProgram;
    se.lpParameters = strArguments;
    se.nShow = SW_SHOWDEFAULT;
    se.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    ShellExecuteEx(&se);

    if (se.hProcess != nullptr)
    {
        do
        {
            dwResult = ::MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, &(se.hProcess), FALSE,
                INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT);
            if (dwResult != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
            {
                while (PeekMessage(&sMessage, nullptr, NULL, NULL, PM_REMOVE))
                {
                    TranslateMessage(&sMessage);
                    DispatchMessage(&sMessage);
                }
            }
        } while ((dwResult != WAIT_OBJECT_0) && (dwResult != WAIT_FAILED));

        CloseHandle(se.hProcess);
    }

    if ((DWORD_PTR)(se.hInstApp) < 33)
    {
        // Throw error
        AfxThrowUserException();
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

But when I run it I get this error message:

[image: Error]

So how can I launch my file in **Microsoft Edge**? I am using the latest Windows 10 so it is **Microsoft Edge Chromium**.

I have seen other questions which refer to making Edge the default browser and then just "opening" the data file and it working it all out but this is not OK in this case. In my editor I have a menu flyout which lists all the installed browsers (excluding  Edge for now). But i want to add Edge so need to be able to programatically start it with my file to view.

Comment: Can you just use `"msedge"` as the `strProgram `and  `"d:\\HTML\\Verticle Alignment.HTM"` as the `strArguments` - I tried that from a console mode program and it worked.

Comment: ... I think "start" is a command-line thing left over from DOS days.

Comment: @AdrianMole Got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments provided to me, and to factor in for spaces in the file name, this works:

```
ExecuteProgram(_T("msedge"), _T("\"d:/HTML/Verticle Alignment.HTM\""));
```

- The program to execute needs to be `msedge` and not `start`.
- The parameter needs to be wrapped in `"` quotes.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.